# Python download zip file and immediately open it

Tags: python, gzip

I am downloading odds from a website which is returned as a zip (.gz) file.
Currently my code is:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)

with open("code2.zip", "wb") as code:
    code.write(f.read())
code.close()

z = gzip.open("code2.zip", "r")
file_content = z.read()
z.close()
root = etree.fromstring(file_content)
```

Is there a way of not saving the file instead storing it in memory as a string and reading that in gzip.open()? Or any other ways I could improve efficiency?

Comment: You don't need the `code.close()`, with will automatically do it for you.

Comment: Are you sure you can expect the content to be properly written/flushed until you explicitly called `close()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage `StringIO.StringIO` package and keep content in memory:

```
in_mem_file = StringIO.StringIO(f.read())
file_content = gzip.open(in_mem_file).read()
```

From [StringIO Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)

> This module implements a file-like class, StringIO, that reads and
>   writes a string buffer (also known as memory files).

Comment: I am getting an TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found at the moment. Just investigating it now. But looks like StringIO is what I was looking for.